# Wordpress widget title

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is there a way to have individual title widget to have a link of their own without using a plugin?

```
register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => __( 'Footer', 'classic' ),
    'id' => 'sidebar-3',
    'description' => __( 'An optional widget area for your site footer', 'classic' ),
    'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => "</aside>",
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
) );
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way than to use a plugin but I refuse to do so. So I have used jQuery to trigger the widget title with specific id and added a link.

```
$("#menu1 h3").wrap('<a href="http://www.google.ca" class="toot"></a>');
```